# How to set Id's for list of EditText within the dynamically created TableLayout in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-tablelayout

I am programmatically creating a dynamic TableLayout with a mixture of TextView and EditText. This TextViews are fetched from the sqlite database of application. The last column of the TableLayout consists of the EditText whose state is set to **Invisible**. I want to set the state of the EditText of the particular row of TableLayout to **Visible** based on the onClick over a row of TableLayout. After onClick, EditText should be visible and I want to store the entry made in that editText within the database.

My code of attempt made for this is below:

```
        List<Details> customerDetailList = db.getAllCustomers(routeId);

        Details customerDetails;

        TableLayout stk = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);

        stk.removeAllViews();

        TableRow tbrow0 = new TableRow(this);
        TextView tv0 = new TextView(this);
        tv0.setText("Sl.No.");
        tv0.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tv0.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        //tv0.setTextSize(20);
        tv0.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        tbrow0.addView(tv0);

        TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
        tv1.setText(" Patron ID ");
        tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tv1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        //tv1.setTextSize(20);
        tv1.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        tbrow0.addView(tv1);

        TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
        tv2.setText(" Name ");
        tv2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        //tv2.setTextSize(20);
        tv2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tv2.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        tv2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tbrow0.addView(tv2);

        TextView tv3 = new TextView(this);
        tv3.setText(" Requested ");
        tv3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tv3.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        //tv3.setTextSize(20);
        tv3.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        tv3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tbrow0.addView(tv3);

        TextView tv4 = new TextView(this);
        tv4.setText(" Supplied ");
        tv4.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        //tv4.setTextSize(20);
        tv4.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tv4.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        tbrow0.addView(tv4);


        tbrow0.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorLightGray);
        stk.addView(tbrow0);


        for (int row = 0, j = 1; row < customerDetailList.size(); row++, j++) {
            customerDetails = customerDetailList.get(row);
            TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(this);
            tbrow.setClickable(true);
            final TextView t1v = new TextView(this);
            t1v.setText("" + j);
            t1v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            t1v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            t1v.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            tbrow.addView(t1v);
            TextView t2v = new TextView(this);
            t2v.setText("" + customerDetails.getcId());
            t2v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            t2v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            t2v.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            tbrow.addView(t2v);
            TextView t3v = new TextView(this);
            t3v.setText("" + customerDetails.getName());
            t3v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            t3v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            t3v.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            tbrow.addView(t3v);
            TextView t4v = new TextView(this);
            t4v.setText("" + customerDetails.getRequested());
            t4v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            t4v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            t4v.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            tbrow.addView(t4v);
            final EditText t5v = new EditText(this);
          //  t5v.setHint(0);
            t5v.setId(j);
            t5v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            t5v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            t5v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            t5v.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            tbrow.addView(t5v);

            tbrow.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorWhite);

        tbrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TableRow tr1=(TableRow)v;
                TextView tv1= (TextView)tr1.getChildAt(0);
                //Get the integer value of tv1 to make the corresponding edittext to be visible
                t5v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),tv1.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
            stk.addView(tbrow);


        }
```

I found similar kind of questions being asked in [How to Set Id in EditText programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32800418/how-to-set-id-in-edittext-programmatically-in-android)
and [Android: Set Edit text or text view id Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22527883/android-set-edit-text-or-text-view-id-programmatically) wherein, solution provided to make use of editText.setId(i) where i is any integer value. but it did not help me with my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the below steps to set the Id's for the programmatically created EditText and to retrieve data entered in the edittext.

Step 1: Make global declaration for edittext and int variable as

```
int idOfEditText;
EditText t5v;
```

Step 2: Setup the Id for editText as

```
 t5v = new EditText(this);
 t5v.setId(Integer.valueOf(j)); //I tried with just j being declared as t5v.setId(j); but it was showing up error with the suggestion as Expected resource of type id in android studio. I have made int variable **j** to loop till list.size()
```

Step 3: Get the id of the row onclick over the table using

```
 tbrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                TableRow tr1=(TableRow)v;
                TextView tv1= (TextView)tr1.getChildAt(0);
                //Get the integer value of tv1 to make the corresponding edittext to be visible
                idOfEditText = Integer.valueOf(tv1.getText().toString());
                t5v = (EditText) findViewById(idOfEditText);

            }
        });
```

Step 4: The data entered in the EditText can be retrieved by

```
t5v = (EditText) findViewById(idOfEditText);
String value = t5v.getText().toString();
Toast.makeText(this, "You entered: "+value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom id in an xml file and set that id using `setId()` method. Here are the steps to do that:

1) Create the file `ids.xml` under `res/values` directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="my_custom_id" type="id" />
</resources>
```

2) Then create your view programmatically and set its id:

```
EditText et = new EditText(getContext());
et.setId(R.id.my_custom_id);
```

That should do the trick.

**EDIT:** You can also do the following if you do not know the number of views to be created and cannot use id's from xml file:

```
et.setId(View.generateViewId());
```

The `generateViewId()` method creates a random unique id for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I want to create list of EditText and set ID to it programmatically. I cannot make use of xml file to set the id for the EditText. As I have no knowledge about the number of EditText that can may be created since it depends on the number of record existing in the table from which I am fetching to display record using table layout.

Comment: @Param then instead of using ids from xml file, you can use `et.setId(View.generateViewId())`. Please let me know if that works.